# IP_HDRINCL option is not supported with IPv6 , how to set ipv6 src addr?

Tags: ipv6

I need setting ipv6 src addr to "::0", but system will set the addr to link-local addr.
I use a raw socket, however, i cant't construct the IP header by myself, IP_HDRINCL option is only supported with IPv4, so how should i do ??

Comment: Question why you think you need to set the source address?